# 10 fold validation error when conducting clustering

Tags: jupyter-notebook, cluster-analysis

An error occurs when applying stratifield 10-fold validation to this model fit.
The following section1 is run without any issue, but when applying the 10-fold validation in section2 the object has no attribute 'fit'.
**The issue is to have the model "remember" the best fitted model, when comparing various models, KNN, DTC, LR, etc. and not only show the best performing Cross validation accuracy for this model only.**

Section1

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier() 
rf.fit(train_feature, train_label)
predictionrf = rf.predict(test_feature)
scores.append(['Random Forest'] + apply_metrics(test_label, predictionrf))
```

SECTION 2

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier() 
rf = cross_val_score(rf, train_feature, train_label, cv = 10)
rf.fit(train_feature, train_label)
predictionrf = rf.predict(test_feature)
scores.append(['Random Forest'] + apply_metrics(test_label, predictionrf))
```

The goal is to do a 10-fold validation on the model, and have it to predict based on the best model obtained. What seems to be the issue with this code?

Comment: Maybe cross-validated SE is a better fit for this?